# How to dynamically generate different google maps

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

Here is the issue I have. I have many businesses and I want to show the google maps for each business (all in one HTML page).

**For each business I have:**

- The latitude and longitude (always).
- The address but sometimes not the street number.

**Question.**

How can I insert a google map for each business using the lat/long or the business using Google Map API?

**Difficulties**

-using ID for each business is not ideal.

-How can I pass the latitude/longitude to a javascript function to insert the map?

**Here is general Idea of what I want to do.**

assume I have an array of businesses that contains information about each business.

```
foreach($businessesList as $businessName =>bInfo)
{
       list($about, addressText, $lat, $long) = $bInfo

       <div> $businessName</div>
       <div> $about</div>
       <div class='map'>
```

//insert google maps inside this div for each business using $lat, $long and Google Maps API.

```
            </div>

}
```

I dont much  experience with javascript and jquery as mostly work with PHP

I can set up an array to containing the Google Maps embed code and basically look up the embedded code for each business but I dont like that.

e.g addressArray =['business1'=>'embed code copied from google maps.', .....]

PS feel free to ask for clarifications.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

so you have php array with all needed data like latlng

then you can iterate over it on php and render html for each item

having html id for each business map **is OK**

some meta code:

```
<?php

$myplaces = [
    [
        'address'=>'Example 1, NY',
        'lat'=>30.123456,
        'lng'=>50.123456
    ],
    [
        'address'=>'Example 2, LA',
        'lat'=>40.123456,
        'lng'=>50.123456
    ],
    //as many you like
];

$unique_id = 0;
foreach($myplaces as $place){    
    ?>
    <h1><?php echo $place['address']; ?></h1>
    <div id="map_<?php echo $unique_id; ?>"></div>
    <script>
    var pos = {lat: <?php echo $place['lat']; ?>, lng: <?php echo $place['lng']; ?>};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_<?php echo $unique_id; ?>'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: pos 
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    $unique_id++;
}
?>
```

docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map

dont forget to include google maps script itself with proper api key

Comment: Thank you Max...I wasnt sure If you can combine Javasccript inside the PHP/HTML code..

Comment: one will say it is commonly bad practice, but in your case perfect